# Function/Do-while to generate random numbers until they are all the same

Tags: javascript, loops, numbers

(Javascript) My goal is to generate 3 random numbers assigned to a,b, and c. I want to do this over and over until a b and c all are the same number while also keeping track of how many tries it takes. However, the only outcome is my "Error" part that I have added for debugging. Any ideas on where I possibly went wrong?

```
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var runs = 0;
function tripleNumbers() {
    while(a!=b && c !=b) {
        a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        runs++;
    }
    if(a == b && a == c) {
        document.write("A: "+a);
        document.write("B: "+b);
        document.write("C: "+c);
        document.write("Total Runs: "+runs);
    }
    else {
        document.write("Error");
    }
}
tripleNumbers();
```

Comment: If `a == b`, the while loop will stop.  But that does not insure that `c == b`.  That logical check is never performed.  You most likely want that to be an OR.

Comment: @Taplar Wouldn't that be the other way around?? If I made it an OR, then only one condition is all thats needed for the while loop to end, no? Doesnt AND ensure that BOTH need to be met before the loop can be exited?

Comment: No, if you make it an OR, it only takes at minimum one conditional for the while loop to continue.

Comment: @Taplar It works now that it is an OR. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @taplar is correct, a `while` loop is essentially saying "keep running this thing repeatedly **while** the following is **true**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(a!=b && c !=b) {
```

The issue is that your logic is being short circuited.  `a != b && c != b` says that you should perform the loop so long as both those conditionals are true.

However, if the first conditional is false, the second one is not evaluated.

So, logically, the most we can assert after that conditional ends is that `a == b`.

If you want to make sure the loop continues so long as **any** of the values are different, you should change it to use an OR.  That way, for the loop to end, it **has** to be true that `a == b` and `c == b`.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, you have to use an OR operator (`||`) instead of AND, because you want to run the loop until either of the inequalities is true:

```
while(a!=b || c!=b){/*...*/}
```

Or negate the entire expression, and use positive equality checks:

```
while(!(a==b && c==b)){/*...*/}
```